# @Tansactional and @Aspect ordering

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop, transactional, aspectj-maven-plugin

I would like to execute my code just before `@Transactional` transaction is started.

```
@Aspect
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
//@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SynchronizerAspect {

  @Pointcut("execution(public * xxx.xxx.services.*.*(..))")
  private void anyServiceOperation() {
  }

  @Around("anyServiceOperation()")
public Object synchronizerAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Synchronizing : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
return joinPoint.proceed();
  }
```

When I call a service method marked as @Transactional I always have my aspect code executed inside the transaction:

```
[INFO] INFO: FETCH created: Fri Oct 30 15:43:11 UTC 2015 duration: 0 connection: 40 statement: 999 resultset: 0
[INFO] paĹş 30, 2015 3:43:11 PM com.mysql.jdbc.log.Slf4JLogger logInfo
[INFO] INFO: QUERY created: Fri Oct 30 15:43:11 UTC 2015 duration: 1 connection: 40 statement: 14 resultset: 15 message: SELECT @@session.tx_isolation
[INFO] paĹş 30, 2015 3:43:11 PM com.mysql.jdbc.log.Slf4JLogger logInfo
[INFO] INFO: FETCH created: Fri Oct 30 15:43:11 UTC 2015 duration: 3 connection: 40 statement: 14 resultset: 15
[INFO] paĹş 30, 2015 3:43:11 PM com.mysql.jdbc.log.Slf4JLogger logInfo
[INFO] INFO: QUERY created: Fri Oct 30 15:43:11 UTC 2015 duration: 1 connection: 40 statement: 999 resultset: 0 message: SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
[INFO] paĹş 30, 2015 3:43:11 PM com.mysql.jdbc.log.Slf4JLogger logInfo
[INFO] INFO: FETCH created: Fri Oct 30 15:43:11 UTC 2015 duration: 0 connection: 40 statement: 999 resultset: 0
[INFO] paĹş 30, 2015 3:43:11 PM com.mysql.jdbc.log.Slf4JLogger logInfo
[INFO] INFO: QUERY created: Fri Oct 30 15:43:11 UTC 2015 duration: 0 connection: 40 statement: 15 resultset: 16 message: SELECT 1
[INFO] paĹş 30, 2015 3:43:11 PM com.mysql.jdbc.log.Slf4JLogger logInfo
[INFO] INFO: FETCH created: Fri Oct 30 15:43:11 UTC 2015 duration: 3 connection: 40 statement: 15 resultset: 16
[INFO] Synchronizing : getCompany
```

I also set `@EnableTransactionManagement(order = 500)`

**Is there something that I should done to make it working?**

Additionally, I use aspectj-maven-plugin:1.7 to weave aspects at the compile time.

Is it so smart and also uses @Ordering?

It doesn't matter how I set @Order aspectj-maven-plugin logs shows that my @Aspect was added before @Transactional

```
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(boolean xxx.xxx.services.LicenseServiceImpl.checkLicenseFile(int, int))' in Type 'xxx.xxx.services.LicenseServiceImpl' (LicenseServiceImpl.java:261) advised by around advice from 'xxx.xxx.aop.SynchronizerAspect' (SynchronizerAspect.java:29)
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(boolean xxx.xxx.services.LicenseServiceImpl.checkLicenseFile(int, int))' in Type 'xxx.xxx.services.LicenseServiceImpl' (LicenseServiceImpl.java:261) advised by around advice from 'org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect' (spring-aspects-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!AbstractTransactionAspect.class:66(from AbstractTransactionAspect.aj))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK. I know the answer:

If Spring's proxy-based AOP is used, @Order annotation works fine.
For load-time weaving it is needed to declare aspect precedence:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.DeclarePrecedence;

@Aspect
@DeclarePrecedence("xxx.xxx.aop.SynchronizerAspect, org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect, *")
public class AspectPrecedence {
  // empty
}
```

To switch from AutoProxy(default) to AspectJ:

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
```