# How solve the problem of that a message consumer try to retrieve an object that has not yet been inserted on DB?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-aop, cqrs, saga

I am implementing a Saga.

After a `SomthingCreated` event is published and then `Something` is retrieved on the other process.

The problem is that `SomthingRepository.findById(somthingCreated.id())` returns null on the other process because the `Something` object is not inserted on DB yet.

```
@Transactional
public String createSomething(long userId, String name) {
        
    String somethingId = somethingRepository.newSomethingId();
    Something something = new Something(userId, name);
    somethingRepository.save(something);
    System.out.println("save:"+System.currentTimeMillis());

    return somethingId;
}
```

the `SomthingCreated` event is published after save() using Aspect

```
@After("execution(* com.some.something.application.*.*(..))")
public void publish() {
    DomainEventPublisher.instance().commitPublishing();
    System.out.println("publish:"+System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

And then, the message consumer invokes application logic.

```
@Transactional
public String handle(SomthingCreated somthingCreated) {
    System.out.println("handle:"+System.currentTimeMillis());       
    Something something = somethingRepository.findById(somthingCreated.id());
    something.do(); //<-- NULLPointerException
}
```

I think
The execution time is like this,
save:1643092272658
publish:1643092272852
handle:1643092272870
(the interval between `publish` and `handle` is faster than the interval between `save` and `publish` although the event passed the network!)

What is that I am missing. I am using JPA and RabbitMQ on Spring.

The repository is like this,

```
@Repository
public class JpaSomethingRepository implements SomethingRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    @Override
    public void save(Something something) {
        entityManager.persist(something);
    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

I could add sleep-method on handle-method and It works but It seems ugly.

I am using entityManager.persist() with  @Transactional but why it is not inserted to DB in the same transaction?

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because of the order in which the `advice` of AOP was applied.

I read this [@Tansactional and @Aspect ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440182/tansactional-and-aspect-ordering)

And then, I added the code below to configure the Aspect order.

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableTransactionManagement(order = 2)
```

```
@Aspect
@Order(1)
public class EventProcessor {
    ...
    
    @After("execution(* com.some.somethin.application.*.*(..))")
    public void publish() {
        DomainEventPublisher.instance().commitPublishing();
    }
}
```

I applied for the order so that more inner @transactional proxy is executed first and then the `EventProcessor` proxy publish event.